# What is the true meaning of the word "roger" when used on the radio? What is its origin?

Tags: radio-communications, terminology

When pilots learn to talk on the radio they can generally learn that the word "roger," when used on the radio, is a way to acknowledge that a message was received. What is the textbook definition of the meaning of this word when used on the radio? Also, what is the origin of this word?

Comment: Obligatory [link](https://youtu.be/fVq4_HhBK8Y)

Comment: @TomMcW Yesssss!

Comment: [JAN phonetic alphabet / Able Baker alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_military_phonetic_spelling_alphabets) successor of first alphabet by ITU (1920) where R was Roma.

Answer (score 10):

In the US, the "textbook" meaning is in the [Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg.pdf):

> **ROGER** − I have received all of your last  transmission. It should not be used to answer a  question requiring a yes or a no answer.

The [AIM 4-2-3](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf) gives an example of using it to acknowledge instructions:

> Acknowledge  with  your aircraft identification, either at the
>   beginning or  at the end of your transmission, and one of the words 
>   “Wilco,” “Roger,” “Affirmative,” “Negative,” or  other appropriate
>   remarks; e.g., “PIPER TWO ONE  FOUR LIMA, ROGER.”

As a counterpoint to that, when I first learned to fly in South Africa I was told never to use *Roger* in transmissions because it doesn't tell the controller anything useful (obviously the FAA disagrees).

And as for the etymology, that's already been covered in [another answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/23751/62):

> This usage comes from the initial R of received: R was called Roger in
>   the radio alphabets or spelling alphabets in use by the military at
>   the time of the invention of the radio

Answer (score 8):

The word "roger" is used to acknowledge that a message was received, and goes back to the early uses of radio. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_procedure):

> This usage comes from the initial R of received: R was called Roger in the radio alphabets or spelling alphabets in use by the military at the time of the invention of the radio

Comment: My understanding is "received and understood".  Is that a common interpretation?

Comment: I think so, it does not mean "I will comply" for which wilco is a shortening of. It just means you have heard and (mentally) made a note.